# How do I add German public holidays to my Outlook 2016 OSX App

Tags: macos, ms-office

How do I add German public holidays to my Outlook 2016 OSX App?

I currently have the UK holidays but want to add the German ones.

Answer (score 4):

It’s true, in Mac Office 2016 there’s no longer an option to add holidays. Also, you can’t download a *.ics calendar file and import it into Mac Office 2016. Both workaround only apply to **Mac Office 2011**, only.

The only way around this is to add your Exchange/CalDAV account to Apple Calendar App. Than import your German-Holiday.ics file to your Exchange account. Finally open Outlook and wait until all calendar items have been synced.

**UPDATE Juni 2019:** I am getting back to my original answer from 2 years ago. In the meantime Microsoft silently added a couple feature to open ics files. Outlook still lacks a import feature in the Import... menu. But user Rick Troiani pointed out a really nice workaround.

**Solution A:** Drag-and-drop your *.ics file right onto my Outlook Calendar.

...You can also use the following workflow:

**Solution B:** Drag-and-drop your *.ics file onto the Outlook icon within the macOS Dock.

**Solution C:** Right click your *.ics file in macOS Finder > Open with Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official Outlook website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-holidays-on-your-calendar-bf1f1b31-7a24-4288-a12e-8e3b692011c4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1):

1. On the File menu, click Import.
2. Click Holidays, and then click the right arrow.
3. Select the countries/regions or religions whose holidays you want to import, and then click the right arrow.
4. Click OK, and then click Finish.

Otherwise, you can download the German calendar and manually import on Outlook, doing the following:

1. Go to [this website](http://www.calendarlabs.com/ical-calendar-holidays.php) (2016 ICAL CALENDAR HOLIDAYS - ICAL, GOOGLE & OUTLOOK).
2. Scroll the list, till you find the German holiday calendar and download it.
3. Import the downloaded file on Outlook, and it's done.

Comment: There is no option (2) Holidays in OSX 2016

Comment: Both answer do not work no longer with Outlook 2016. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: You can now do this from the web version and it get an update on your outlook app accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

The application indeed doesn't have the functionality. But there is a workaround with the online calendar.
Sign-in online through Office 365,
Navigate to Outlook > Calendar
Click 'Add new calendar' in the ribbon and select the sub-option: 'Holiday calendar'

After you've selected the country of choice you will see it added to the calendar collection. 
Next return to the application and (at least for me) it synced and added the holiday calendar of my country.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download a US calendar from the site above, and dragged it right onto my outlook calendar (Mac Mojave, Office 365, Outlook), and Viola, it worked.  I have a different issue, so couldn't log into Office online due to some issue at work.  Looks like the Import instructions are no longer necessary in the outlook client.  You just need a .ics calendar file.

Comment: Excellent point. Thanks for sharing. It looks like Microsoft added this workaround. I have updated my original answer from 2017.